# Bootstrap 3 col-xs-12 affect others screen siez

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a block that take full width on mobile, but 3/12 columns on others screen.

So I have a `.container` class, then a `row` class, and finally I have a `<div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">`.

**What I have**
When I add the `.col-xs-12` this affect the result on large, medium and small screen !

**What I would like**
Take col-lg-3 on large, medium and small screen. And full width on mobile (col-xs-12)

Do you have an idea ?

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
    </div>


    <a href="#"
       class="lien active">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            Bétons
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#"
       class="lien active">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            Sables, graviers ...
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 conseil-et-devis-gratuits">
        <p>CONSEILS ET DEVIS GRATUITS</p>
        <img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
        <p>Lundi au vendredi : 8h-12h - 13h-18h - Samedi : 8h-12h</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a double `col-sm-4 col-sm-4` in your last `<div>`. and I think `col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-12` will be a problem in your first `<div>`. Shouldn't this be: `col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9`

Comment: Ok I correct it, but it still doesn't working ...

Comment: Try changing these 

`<a href="#" class="lien active"><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Sables, graviers ...</div></a>`

to `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#" class="lien active">Sables, graviers ...</a></div>`

Comment: @StavrosAngelis Even if I change link in div, the first image will not work, but I'll try later, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you want, you need to reset the offset for larger screens:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0"></div>
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

If all you want is full width on mobile then you wouldn't need to be using offset at all.

`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>` would be good enough.

Comment: `col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-9 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-0` work perfectly ! Thanks

Comment: Great! Just as a headsup, you don't need to repeat md and lg classes if they are the same as sm! Just using col-sm-3 will apply to small devices as well as anything larger than that. Saves you some code.